# Regex problem C#

Tags: c#, regex

```
 const string strRegex =
    @"(?<city_country>[^.]+) (cca|ca.|ungefähr) (?<price>[\d.,]+) (eur)?";
 searchQuery = RemoveSpacesFromString(searchQuery);
 Regex regex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 Match m = regex.Match(searchQuery);
 ComplexAdvertismentsQuery query = new ComplexAdvertismentsQuery();

 if (m.Success)
```

while "Agadir ca. 600" is false but "Agadir ca. 600 eur" is true. "eur" is optional but "Agadir ca. 600" is false? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose `eur` in parenthesis, like so `(eur)?`.

`?` matches the preceding *character* zero or one times. By enclosing it in the parens, it will match the whole word.

Also, maybe it is matching the last space before `(eur)?`. Try this:

`@"(?<city_country>[^.]+) (cca|ca.|ungefähr) (?<price>[\d.,]+)(\seur)?"`

Notice, I removed the last white space and added `\s`, which matches any white space including space, tab, form-feed, etc.

Comment: I think so, but testing it will give you definitive answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write `(eur)?` instead of `eur?`. I.e. place the Space  before also inside the parenthesis

Comment: is the same even if i use (eur)?

Comment: I modified my answer. Place the space before also *inside* the parenthesis like `( eur)?`.

Answer (score 0):

Using (eur)? instead of eur? should solve the problem.

best way would be `@"(?<city_country>[^.]+) (cca|ca.|ungefähr) (?<price>[\d.,]+)\s*(\seur)?")` putting space *only* inside like ( eur) would not match something like "Agadir ca. 600 "

Comment: is the same even if i use (eur)?

Comment: maybe you can just try with eur? and (eur)?, without the previous part of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
@"(?<city_country>[^.]+) (cca|ca.|ungefähr) (?<price>[\d.,]+)( eur)?"

OR

@"(?<city_country>[^.]+) (cca|ca.|ungefähr) (?<price>[\d.,]+)(\seur)?"
```